# A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context error

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the function that is defined within the C code:

```c
typedef void (*spAnimationStateListener)(spAnimationState *state, spEventType type, spTrackEntry *entry, spEvent *event);

struct spTrackEntry {
    ...
    spAnimationStateListener listener;
    ...
};
```

And, I am trying to use it in Swift like this:

```swift
class TrackEntry {
    private let ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<spTrackEntry>!

    public func addEventListener(_ eventListener: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let listener: spAnimationStateListener = { (state, type, entry, event) in
            eventListener() //cannot use this
           
        }        
        ptr.pointee.listener = listener
    }
}
```

I saw some suggestion like passing "self" as a parameter but I could not figure out how to do that. I cannot change the C code and it is accepting four parameters. I also tried `unsafeBitCast` by using `convention(block)` and it compiled but data were broken.

I cannot use it as a static variable because listeners are separate between different TrackEntry instances.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, C function pointers can only be called from static or global context.

There is a good reason : in C, functions are only declared in global context - ie. in the memory dedicated to instructions storage, not in the memory dedicated to data storage. You cannot have *instances* of a function. A function pointer can just *point to* one function or another. You cannot create code on-the-fly, neither pass it *by value*. You can only point to one part of the instructions or another.

So, if only one listener can be used at a time, you could declare a global variable for the closure, and change it before the listener is created, pointing to this listener ; and when another listener is created replace it.
But if you have several listeners at once, well you will have  to globally create a closure for each of them (if you do not have too much, and not too generic).

Comment: I need to pass a customized swift function to use it at a high level. Otherwise, I need to edit this low level function every time I add extra events or something. Is there any other solutions?

Comment: I do not see another solution, but maybe someone else will.

Comment: But nothing prevents to assign a global function from the `addEventListener()`, if there is not too many event listeners. But anyway, yes you will have to change this for each new listener...